# rpy2 running R function

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have an R function

```
 square_num <- function(x) {
     return(x*x)
 }
```

when I run this via rpy2 as:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage as STAP
string = """
square_num <- function(x) {
     return(x*x)
}    
"""

testy = STAP(string, "testy")

Jack = testy.square_num(10)
print(Jack)
```

it works.

When I have the function inside an R file and run it using

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage as STAP
with open('Algo.r', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()

testy = STAP(string, "testy")

Jack = testy.square_num(10)
print(Jack)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 25, in <module>
    testy = STAP(string, "testy")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line     290,  in __init__
reval(string, env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 75, in reval
p = rinterface.parse(string)
rpy2.rinterface.RParsingError
```

The function is the same in both instances. I just copied and pasted it into a .r file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the content of your Python variable `string` ?

The following should work:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage as STAP
string = """
square_num <- function(x) {
     return(x*x)
}    
"""

testy = STAP(string, "testy")

Jack = testy.square_num(10)
print(Jack)

with open('algo.R', 'w') as fh_out:
    fh_out.write(string)

with open('algo.R', 'r') as f:
    string_again = f.read()

testy = STAP(string_again, "testy")

Jack = testy.square_num(10)
print(Jack)
```

Comment: yes that works. I think it might be windows and linux line endings......

Comment: It could also be the encoding.